# Android: Disable Menu Item if EditText has Error

Tags: android, validation

I'm validating an EditText on an Activity with this code which inside the onCreate() method:

```
final EditText editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleNameTextView);
editName.addTextChangedListener(
        new TextWatcher() {
            @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
            @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
            @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(editName.getText().toString().length() < 3){
                    editName.setError("Error Text");
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

So If i do:

```
Log.d("error", editName.getError().toString());
```

I get the message.

Now I want to enable/disable a menu item depending if this editText has errors. I found I can modify the availability of the button with this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_people_edit, menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_save).setEnabled(false);
    return true;
}
```

The problem is that I cant disable the button when I set the error message because I have to modify it within the onCreateOptionsMenu and the validation is made from the onCreate method.

EDIT: I added the following code but it isnt working

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleNameTextView);
    if(name.getText().toString().length() < 3){
        menu.getItem(0).setEnabled(false);
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Keep a reference to your menu from `onCreateOptionsMenu`. You can enable/disable within your `TextWatcher` then.

Answer (score 2):

you have to call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`, or the version backwards compatible. It will call `onCreateOptionsMenu`. There you can check your condition, and do whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

Changing menu items at runtime

> Once the activity is created, the  onCreateOptionsMenu() method is
>   called only once, as described above. The system keeps and re-uses the
>   Menu you define in this method until your activity is destroyed. If
>   you want to change the Options Menu any time after it's first created,
>   you must override the onPrepareOptionsMenu() method. This passes you
>   the Menu object as it currently exists. This is useful if you'd like
>   to remove, add, disable, or enable menu items depending on the current
>   state of your application.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.getItem(0).setEnabled(false); 
       return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Comment: as commented below you must call invalidateOptionsMenu() when you want to update the menu, because the menu is always open. The system will then call onPrepareOptionsMenu() so you can update the menu items.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some answers I made it the next way

1- I Added this method:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleNameTextView);
    if(name.getText().toString().length() < 3){
        menu.getItem(0).setEnabled(false);
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

2- When I set the error I also call:

```
invalidateOptionsMenu()
```